# Log out view in Django not working. It says method not allow

Tags: python, django

I tried using Django built in views to create a log out route
But it doesn't work. It says method not allow

I expected it to log out a user but it doesn't. Always getting error with that. But I imported the login view from Django views and it's working but the log out says method not allowed .Wish someone could help me

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: You used the wrong method to initiate the logout.